# Find the eigenvalues of A, given A and its eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

I'm having trouble starting to solve this. Do I solve it with an augmented matrix? Can someone walk me through the first one so I know how to solve the rest?

Comment: **Hint**: $A[0,-1,1]^T=-2[0,-1,1]^T$ which implies $-2$ is an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One usual method for calculating the eigenvalue $\lambda$ of a matrix $A$ from one of its eigenvectors $v$ is the [Rayleigh-quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient)
\begin{align*}
\lambda = \frac{v^* A v}{v^* v}
\end{align*}
If the eigenvectors are real as in your example this is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
\lambda = \frac{v^T A v}{v^T v}
\end{align*}
The formula works since with $Av=\lambda v$ you get
\begin{align*}
\frac{v^* A v}{v^* v} = \frac{v^* \lambda v}{v^* v} = \lambda \frac{v^* v}{{v^* v}}= \lambda.
\end{align*}
This method also works for approximative eigenvalues corresponding to approximative eigenvectors where it is not so simple to recognize per inspection that $Av$ is a multiple of $v$.

Answer (score 0):

Eigenvalues and eigenvectors have the property that $Av=\lambda v$ where $A$ is your matrix, $v$ is an eigenvector, and $\lambda$ is an eigenvector. Then, for any of your eigenvectors, we can find the corresponding eigenvalue by solving the equation $Av=\lambda v$. For example, using the first eigenvector, we get:

$\begin{pmatrix}3&0&0\\0&-2&0\\2&3&1 \end{pmatrix}*\begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\\1 \end{pmatrix}=\lambda \begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\\1 \end{pmatrix} \implies \begin{pmatrix}0\\2\\-2 \end{pmatrix}=\lambda \begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\\1 \end{pmatrix} \implies \lambda=-2$

Thus, for the first eigenvector, we see that the corresponding eigenvalue is $-2$. Now follow this process for the other two to get the other eigenvalues.